# Can mypy handle list comprehensions?

Tags: python, python-3.x, type-hinting, mypy, python-typing

```
from typing import Tuple
def test_1(inp1: Tuple[int, int, int]) -> None:
    pass

def test_2(inp2: Tuple[int, int, int]) -> None:
    test_tuple = tuple(e for e in inp2)
    reveal_type(test_tuple)
    test_1(test_tuple)
```

While running `mypy` on the above code, I get:

```
error: Argument 1 to "test_1" has incompatible type "Tuple[int, ...]"; expected "Tuple[int, int, int]"
```

Is `test_tuple` not guaranteed to have 3 `int` elements? Does `mypy` not handle such list comprehensions or is there another way of defining the type here?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As of version 0.600, `mypy` does not infer types in such cases. It would be hard to implement, as suggested on [GitHub](https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/5068#issuecomment-389882867).

Instead, we can use `cast` (see [mypy docs](http://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/casts.html)):

```
from typing import cast, Tuple

def test_1(inp1: Tuple[int, int, int]) -> None:
    pass

def test_2(inp2: Tuple[int, int, int]) -> None:
    test_tuple = cast(Tuple[int, int, int], tuple(e for e in inp2))
    reveal_type(test_tuple)
    test_1(test_tuple)
```