# Why is mypy complaining about list comprehension when it can't be annotated?

Tags: python, type-hinting, mypy, python-typing

Why does Mypy complain that it requires a type annotation for a list comprehension variable, when it is impossible to annotate such a variable using MyPy?

Specifically, how can I resolve the following error:

```
from enum import EnumMeta

def spam( y: EnumMeta ):
    return [[x.value] for x in y]  Mypy: Need type annotation for 'x'
```

***`cast` doesn't work***:

```
return [[cast(Enum, x).value] for x in y]  Mypy: Need type annotation for 'x'
```

Even though Mypy doesn't support annotations (`x:Enum`) in such a case I see the **usage** of the variable can be annotated using `cast` ([see this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49008718/can-mypy-handle-list-comprehensions)). However, `cast(Enum, x)`  doesn't stop Mypy complaining that the variable isn't annotated in the first place.

***`#type:` doesn't work***:

```
return [[x.value] for x in y] # type: Enum  Mypy: Misplaced type annotation
```

I also see that a **`for`** loop variable can be annotated using a comment, `# type:` ([see this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41641449/how-do-i-annotate-types-in-a-for-loop)). However, `# type: Enum` doesn't work for list comprehension's `for`.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

In a list comprehension, the iterator must be cast instead of the elements.

```
from typing import Iterable, cast
from enum import EnumMeta, Enum

def spam(y: EnumMeta):
    return [[x.value] for x in cast(Iterable[Enum], y)]
```

This allows `mypy` to infer the type of `x` as well. In addition, at runtime it performs only 1 cast instead of n casts.

If `spam` can digest *any* iterable that produces enums, it is easier to type hint this directly.

```
from typing import Iterable
from enum import Enum

def spam(y: Iterable[Enum]):
    return [[x.value] for x in y]
```

Answer (score 5):

MisterMyagi's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60670154/13990016) is the best solution for this specific case. It may be worth noting, however, that it is also possible to declare the type of a variable before that variable is defined. The following also [passes MyPy](https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=latest&python=3.10&flags=strict&gist=4c17dcc2836ee27e1c11279ab6309d76):

```
from enum import Enum

def spam(y: type[Enum]):
    x: Enum
    return [[x.value] for x in y]
```